# R8 vs ProGuard - keep rules

Tags: android, gradle, optimization, proguard, android-r8

My understanding is that R8 (Google) and ProGuard (Guardsquare) are different products that can't work together.

Now, in the latest gradle versions, Android Studio enables R8 by default and the configurations and rules for keeping classes from the optimizations are set, by default, in the `proguard-rules.pro` file following the same style/rules as ProGuard (which is confusing but enabled an easy migration).

- What is your experience in disabling R8 and setting ProGuard instead with the rules that you used to have in the `proguard-rules.pro`?
- Did you have to adapt them? Was it a drastic change?

In my experience, I have a working app shrinked with R8 and after disabling it and enabling ProGuard with the same rules it crashes and I have to adapt the rules.

Is/Was this your case too?

Comment: Put this in your `proguard-rules.pro` : `-printconfiguration ~/tmp/full-r8-config.txt` and it'll show you all the rules, you might see extras you weren't expecting

Comment: No, R8 (compiler) actually uses proguard (obfuscation and optimizatio) rules.
So it's not clear on what you meant by "disabling R8".

Comment: @ltp https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/setup/gradleplugin the official documentation says that if you want to use ProGuard you need to disable R8

Comment: I see. But R8 is using proguard rules and some automatically generated rules.
https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#configuration-files

Comment: Yes, but the rules are only for compatibility purposes, the paragraph above states that R8 does not use ProGuard https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#:~:text=the%20plugin%20no%20longer%20uses%20ProGuard